# SignIn Methods are coming as empty list even if it is showing firebase authentication console

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

```
auth.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(emailtxt)
           .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
           val result = task.result
         val signInMethods = result?.signInMethods

       Log.d("Methods", signInMethods.toString())   // It is COming as []

         if (signInMethods != null && signInMethods.contains(
                 EmailAuthProvider.EMAIL_PASSWORD_SIGN_IN_METHOD) && signInMethods.contains(
                                                    GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
                                                )
                                            ) {
                                                emailedit.error = "Email already registered"
                                                emailedit.requestFocus()
                                            }
```

I searched about it but didn't find any solution.
Thank you!

Previously around 3 months ago on my different Android project, it was working fine but now it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(java.lang.String)) function is deprecated due to the [Email Enumeration Protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection). That's because malicious users can perform an email enumeration attack on your Firebase project.

Unfortunately, there is no workaround in the long term. However, in a short time, you can disable the email enumeration protection in the Firebase Console:

[image]

To make the `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail()` function work, but I recommend against it. If this method disappears in the future, please note that there is no alternative API and no workaround.

What I recommend is to try to change the flow of your project in such a way that you can avoid such an operation.

Comment: So how is one supposed to check if a user with the given email exists? All answers that come up use `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`

Comment: @parsecer Unfortunately, there is no solution in the long term